# Не появляется изображение в области

Tags: java, javafx

Сложность в том, что не понимаю, почему в экран не вставляется изображение, выводит белый экран и всё. И ещё, где можно почитать хорошую книгу по JavaFX? Cпасибо

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
      public static Pane pane = new Pane();
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
          try {
            Image image = new Image("picture//BackGround.jpg");
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          primaryStage.setTitle("JGame");
          primaryStage.setWidth(1024);
          primaryStage.setHeight(768);
          primaryStage.show();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить .fxml файл и определить туда ImageView окно, и после в контроллере этого .fxml файла написать вот это (или просто определите ImageView как я и добавьте его):

```java
public class Page implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        imageView.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/images/YourImage.jpg")));
    }
}
```

P.S. Используйте лучше .fxml файлы и Scene Builder для работы с ними, удачи)